# DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra 3.2 on Cassandra 3.10

Tags: cassandra, compatibility, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

Support is explicitly listed for Cassandra 3.0 here http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/javaDrivers.html#java-drivers and they also list versions like 2.1 and 2.2 explicitly so I don't really want to just assume 3.10 is ok if 3.0 is

I'm not sure if 3.10 will be supported though. Does anyone know? It looks like it probably is, but maybe someone can say for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Datastax Driver 3.2 will work on Apache Cassandra 3.10**

Apache Cassandra 3.x supported protocol version v4, Only the datastax driver 3.x uses protocol version v4.

Check this link for more details : http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/native_protocol/#compatibility-matrix